# How can edit a executable file linux

Tags: files

Hi all i have a file and ist run on my ubuntu server and need to edit it but cant . i open with notepad ++ and get this

[image]

How can edit

Comment: Try to look/google for IDA for Linux...

Comment: need to change some lines

Comment: What does "need to change some lines" mean? Do you mean there is *text* that is shown when you run the program, and you want some other text to be shown instead? Or do you mean something else? I recommend [edit]ing this question to include a detailed description of the specific problem you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: Executable binary image files do not contain "lines" which you could "edit" so the question makes no sense.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309771/disassembling-modifying-and-then-reassembling-a-linux-executable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit any file. The only question is whether this makes sense. For binary files you can use a hexeditor, eg. `hexedit`:

```
sudo apt-get install hexedit
```

E.G.:

```
hexedit /bin/bash
```

[image]

But if you want to change the code, from which the binary was created, then you need the source code.

As an example, for the file  used above you can find the source code [here](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/).

---

You can also try to decompile the file. Download *REC Studio 4 - Reverse Engineering Compiler* from [here](http://www.backerstreet.com/rec/recdload.htm).

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386
cd
mkdir RecStudioLinux
cd RecStudioLinux
wget http://www.backerstreet.com/rec/RecStudioLinux.tgz
tar xf RecStudioLinux.tgz
cd bin
```

and start with:

```
./RecStudioLinux
```

[image]

Comment: can you do this for me i send files . i try and get this ./RecStudioLinux: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libstdc++6 libstdc++6:i386`

Comment: Can you drop by the chat for a bit more info on RecStudioLinux?